# Browser tab badge notification with out changing favicon

Tags: javascript, html, favicon

Is there any way to have a badge for notification in the browser's tab without changing the favicon?

Comment: I'm really not sure what has been asked, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65719387/browser-tab-badge-notification)?

Comment: can you editted your question to give the example picture

Comment: ... Or rather an example code of how you are currently making a "_browser tab badge notification_".